# Unable to disable kernel module

Tags: fedora, kernel, modprobe, dracut

I'm trying to disable kernel module for my motherboard's bluetooth chip: `btintel`.

I've added a blacklist entry to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-btintel.conf` (I also tried blacklist.conf, this didn't make a difference):

```
blacklist btintel
```

I have also symlinked this file to `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/` because of [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=873220) possible issue.

Furthermore, I've edited `/etc/sysconfig/grub`, to include the module in both `rd.driver.blacklist` as well as `modprobe.blacklist`:

```
$ grep 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX' /etc/sysconfig/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau,btintel modprobe.blacklist=nouveau,btintel nvidia-drm.modeset=1 resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_localhost-live/swap rhgb quiet"
```

Afterwards, I've tried running both:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

as well as

```
sudo dracut -fv
```

But after rebooting, I'm still presented with a loaded module:

```
$ lsmod | grep btintel
btintel                28672  1 btusb
bluetooth             626688  48 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `blacklist bluetooth`, too. It depends on `btintel`.

Comment: @IporSircer I don't want to blacklist bluetooth, as it should still load btbcm module  (another bluetooth chip).

Comment: Then recompile the kernel after disable `BT_INTEL` in `.config`.

Comment: @IporSircer thanks for the suggestion, but I ended up just disallowing the device using udev rules, this works in my case: https://blog.evad.io/2018/01/11/disabling-the-built-in-bluetooth-and-use-a-usb-adaptor-instead-on-linux/

Comment: another xyproblem...

Answer (score 0):

You also need to create a file in modprobe.d (filename doesn't really matter).
I'm on RedHat, and the directory is /etc/modprobe.d. I'm guessing it's in the same place on Fedora.
`echo "blacklist btintel" >> /etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth.conf
echo "install btintel /bin/false >> /etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth.conf"`

Note: `/bin/true` also works

See this article from [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41278). II did not have to log in to read this article.